# Non-strong references not working in playground

Tags: swift, xcode6

I was reading the swift programming guide, and in the initializers chapters I came across this code:

```
class Customer {
    let name: String
    var card: CreditCard?
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    deinit { println("\(name) is being deinitialized") }
} 

class CreditCard {
    let number: Int
    unowned let customer: Customer
    init(number: Int, customer: Customer) {
        self.number = number
        self.customer = customer
    }
    deinit { println("Card #\(number) is being deinitialized") }
}
```

So I tried to try the code myself and make some changes to see what happens (makes me understand more )

So I opened the playground and started typing, after that I noticed that the `weak` keyword and the `unowned` keyword aren't recognized by the playground. This could only mean that playground only support strong reference variables.

So why does playground only support strong reference, and what could you do to prevent a strong reference cycle in playground?

Comment: What do you mean by saying that "the weak keyword and the unowned keyword aren't recognized by the playground"? What is your test or proof for that claim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The playground is only a playground. It isn't a very exact representative of real life. So you should not be surprised if it treated memory management differently from real life. (Another example: the top level of a playground is clearly not like the top level of a real Swift file, since you can put things there that are not declarations and they work.)

You can use a playground for developing algorithms interactively, but only real life (i.e. a compilable executable *.swift* file) is real life.

For example, I put this in the App Delegate of an actual iOS app:

```
import UIKit

class Customer {
    let name: String
    var card: CreditCard?
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    deinit { println("\(name) is being deinitialized") }
}

class CreditCard {
    let number: Int
    unowned let customer: Customer
    init(number: Int, customer: Customer) {
        self.number = number
        self.customer = customer
    }
    deinit { println("Card #\(number) is being deinitialized") }
}

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

        var cust = Customer(name:"Matt")
        var cc = CreditCard(number:1234, customer:cust)
        cust.card = cc

        return true
    }
}
```

I saw the two `println` messages, proving that there was *no* retain cycle. If I deleted the `unowned` keyword and ran again, I *didn't* see the two `println` messages, proving that there *was* a retain cycle. Thus we know that `unowned` does what it is advertised to do. That's all we need to know. What works or doesn't work in a playground isn't terribly important.

Comment: If you have a problem with playgrounds, file a bug report, but personally I think the Apple folks have bigger fish to fry just now. Personally I can barely get playgrounds to work at all.

Comment: Ya I noticed that as well , but you mentioned something that I have encountered before when I tried to copy some playground code to a real project ,"top level" , I would appreciate if you could explain to me what is meant by top level

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a console app (New Project > macOS > Command Line Tool)
This way, you don't need to have simulator running when you run your code.

Comment: Hi~ Small answers should go in comments section