# Reference count in Playground

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

Why do I get the following behaviour in playground?

```
class A {
}

class B {
    weak var theA: A?
}

let a = A()
_getRetainCount(a) // output is 2 . OK.
var b = B()
b.theA = a
_getRetainCount(a) // output is 3 . WHY?.
```

As you can see the reference in class B is weak to the A object but playground somehow increases this count.

This doesn't happen in a normal project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600008/non-strong-references-not-working-in-playground, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082011/weak-references-in-swift-playground-dont-work-as-expected.

Comment: And of course: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount

Comment: @MartinR You are all present in the iOS related questions (at least) :)) . Thanks for your answer! I was googling and found these answers as well and ofc playground is not reliable but I was curios if there was any setting or some piece of documentation I missed.